# PHP framework choice to build enterprise-grade SOAP server

Tags: php, web-services, soap, enterprise

For an upcoming project a SOAP webservice has to be developed in PHP. The choice of language/environment has already been made, cannot be affected by me.

This must become an enterprise-grade application supporting business critical processes.

I will need a framework for structure, database abstraction etc. I know Zend Framework is used for these type of apps, but I don't have experience with it. I also not sure about the learning curve.

I have some experience with Yii framework and I like it. Also, I know it has some support for SOAP including WSDL generation.

Does anyone have experience with big apps build with Yii and more specific Yii and SOAP? Are there any other know solutions I don't mention here?

Edit: the webservice must comply with WS-Security as well; does ZF provide means to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend Symfony2.
It's a new, highly scalable framework that's somewhat based on RoR/Spring.

I could describe it's features for hours, so I'll just give you the link to the website:
http://symfony.com/

http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/web_services/php_soap_extension.html

Also, it's very easy to incorporate 3rd party libraries to the symfony2 - probably Zend_Soap would interest you.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I want to advise you to use Zend Framework. Especially Zend_Soap. It is very easy to use. It has WSDL autogeneration, adapters to the DB and etc. [Tutorial](http://plutov.by/post/web_service_soap)

Comment: I have used the Zend Framework to make calls to Google's calendar API using SOAP (and display calendar events in my web page). It's MVC structure is elegant, and I would say that the learning curve it has is definitely worth it. ZF makes it very easy to consume and provide web services thanks to it's WSDL support.